# Loop spaces and smash product

Tags: algebraic-topology, loop-spaces

For context, my question stems from a claim of [Waldhausen](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0074449) (page 342) where from a map
$$|wS.\mathcal{A}|\wedge |wS.\mathcal{B}|\to |wwS.S.\mathcal{C}|.$$
He claims it induces a map
$$\Omega|wS.\mathcal{A}|\wedge \Omega|wS.\mathcal{B}|\to \Omega^2|wwS.S.\mathcal{C}|.$$

This is just context, it is fine to just rename all three spaces to $X,Y$ and $Z$ for the purposes of my confusion, I gave detailed context "just in case".

I am assuming this is the consequence of a result of the form $\Omega(X\wedge Y)\simeq \Omega X\wedge Y$, which would be enough for my purposes. But I have no idea why this would be the case, in fact intuitively this feels false. So does the result stem from something else? Am I missing something obvious? Or is their something even slightly subtle going on here?

Thank you to anybody who has the time to answer my question, it is highly appreciated.

Comment: It could be induced as follows: there is a map $\Omega X\wedge\Omega Y\rightarrow\Omega^2(X\wedge Y)$ given by smashing two loops (this might require point-set hypotheses to work) and then post-compose with $\Omega^2$ of the given pairing. The homotopy-equivalence you state certainly does not hold, e.g. $\Omega(S^1\wedge S^1)=\Omega S^2$ has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$ whereas $\Omega S^1\wedge S^1=\Sigma\Omega S^1\simeq\Sigma\mathbb{Z}$ has infinitely generated fundamental group.